# Jquery : Even if the checkbox is checked, it is always returning false

Tags: jquery

```
$("td.chkboxalarm", this).is(':checked')
```

Even if the checkbox is **checked**, this statement is always returning **false**.

**chkboxalarm**: is the class for each check box in the table.

Answer (score 2):

You are selecting the `td` elements, not the `input` elements.

You should change this to

```
$("input.chkboxalarm", this).is(':checked')
```

or, if the `chkboxalarm` class is actually applied to `td`,

```
$(".chkboxalarm input", this).is(':checked')
```